# Get similar entities in Symfony using Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql

I have a Entity in Symfony for Videos. Lets say the db looks like this:

```
id: int
name: varchar
uploader: int (User Entity)
video_mp4: varchar
param1: int
param2: int
param3: int
```

I'd like to load similar videos. Similar means:

- Or same Uploader
- Or same Param1
- Or same Param2
- Or same Param3

Actually I'd like to order them by the most matchings (meaning a video uploaded by the same user and with same param1 + param3 should be more important then one where just param2 is matching) something like `ORDER BY mostMatches DESC` any ideas how to achive that
For this I'd use this query (yes I know that "OR" isn't good for the DB, sugestions welcome ;))

I created in my Entity class a function that looks like this: ($q is a QueryBuilder)

```
public function getRelated($q, $limit = 6) {
    $uploader = $this->getUploader()->getId();
    $param1 = $this->getParam1();
    $param2 = $this->getParam2();
    $param3 = $this->getParam3();

    $q->select('e')
    ->from('MyBackendBundle:Video','e')
    ->where('e.id != ?0')
    ->andWhere('e.uploader = ?1 OR e.param1 = ?2 OR e.param2 = ?3 OR e.param3 = ?4');

    if ($limit > 0) {
        $q->setMaxResults($limit);
    }

    $q->setParameters(array(
        $this->id,
        $uploader,
        $param1,
        $param2,
        $param3
    ));

    return $q->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Two questions:

1. How can I get the QueryBuilder in an Entity, I don't like to pass it from my Controller.
2. Is there a better way to load similar entries?
3. How can I order them by the most similarities (uploader, param1, param2, param3), sure I could do this with PHP but what if result 7 would be a 100% match but I load only 6?

Comment: 1. Instead, use custom repository class - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Comment: I had it first in my video repository class, but then decided to move it to the Entity, because otherwise I'd need to pass the id, param1, param2, param3 (and in reallife a few other things like visible, published_date, and so on) to that function.
In the Entity I can get all those functions out of the Entity itself with $this->...

Comment: You can use your entity in Repository class. Instead of `$this->...` it will be `$entity->...`.

Comment: Nice. Didn't know this. But I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sum all these matchings:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (CAST(e.uploader = ?1 AS UNSIGNED)
    + CAST(e.param1 = ?2 AS UNSIGNED)
    + CAST(e.param2 = ?3 AS UNSIGNED)
    + CAST(e.param3 = ?4 AS UNSIGNED)
    ) AS matches_count
FROM video
ORDER BY matches_count DESC
```

Comment: This is just plain MySQL right? But how can I use it with Doctrine? When I add `$q->select('e, (CAST(e.uploader = ?0 AS UNSIGNED) + CAST(e.param1 = ?1 AS UNSIGNED)) AS matches_count')` and put `>orderBy('matches_count', 'DESC')` I get an exception `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 11: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'`. Andy idea how to write it with Doctrine?

Comment: You can create Native query (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

Comment: I'll give it a try. But that means there is no true Doctrine way right?

Comment: Native query - is true Doctrine way:-) But you can also use DQL (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html). It is very similar to SQL. Try it first.

Comment: true Native query is Doctrine. What I ment was if there ain't no way to achive it with DQL. I'd prefere DQL because in real live there are a few other fields in that table and in DQL I can just call `where()`, `andWhere()`, `orderBy()`, `andOrderBy`, and so on for a query. For example I have the locale in the db and `$locale` is an optional parameter for the function. With the DQL functions it's just easier then to write the hole query. (Or can I use those functions with Native Querys too?)

Comment: You can do it with builder, with DQL, with SQL (Native query). You can do everything. It's just matter of taste.

Comment: So how would I then do the above Query with the `CAST` stuff with the Query Builder to order it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63482/discussion-between-michael-sivolobov-and-wawa).